# Hide picked items in a FlatList

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using react-native FlatList to render out a punch on elements the data of which comes from an external API.

I want to prevent the user from picking the same item twice. So the way I'm going about this it hiding the item after they pick it.

If, let's say, I have a state `picked` like so

```
  const [ picked, setPicked ] = useState(false);
```

changing it will of course hide all the elements.

```
      <FlatList
        {/*some other props*/}
        data={allCards}
        renderItem={(card: ListRenderItemInfo<CardsProps>) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[ styles.holder, { display: picked ? "none" : "flex" } ]}
            onPress={() => handleChoice(parseInt(card.item.id))}
          >
            <Card
             {/*some card props*/}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
```

How can I go about changing the state for only one element inside the FlatList??
Is there a better approach you would recommend to do the same job?

Answer (score 0):

try it like this, it will work,

```
<FlatList
        {/*some other props*/}
        data={allCards}
        renderItem={(card: ListRenderItemInfo<CardsProps>) => picked ? (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[ styles.holder, ]}
            onPress={() => handleChoice(parseInt(card.item.id))}
          >
            <Card
             {/*some card props*/}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ): undefined}
      />
```

Comment: Nope! same problem. 
on picking one card all the cards disappear.

Comment: that's because you have only one state and checking by that state, so when you set that state to true, it will disappear the other, so you need to check the cards by any attribute like id or index or something else, and you have to check it by that, that your card is selected or not.

Comment: yes, that's exactly the problem I'm facing.  can you please give me an example of how to make the state only change for one element inside the list

Comment: take an array where you will add items to that array during selecting cards, and then take a function where you should check that the card is selected or not(from your new array where you put all your selected cards). if the card is available in the new array you should remove that from the allCards array.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is if you create an object with all the ids and while inserting it you can check it whether it's in that list or not
it'll cost u O(1) time to check.

```
<FlatList
    {/*some other props*/}
    data={allCards}
    renderItem={(card: ListRenderItemInfo<CardsProps>) => picked ? (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[ styles.holder, ]}
        onPress={() => handleChoice(parseInt(card.item.id))}
      >
        <Card
         {/*some card props*/}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ): undefined}
  />
const map=new Map();
    const handleChoice=(id)=>{
if(Map.get(id)===undefined){
Map.set(id,true)
//add the element to ur list where u need it to
}
    }
```